# Computerscience Branch definite Article ( Gender )

Tags: gender, article, loanword

Which definite Article is correctly used for the word "branch"?

Examples:
"Ich werde die Branch auschecken."
or
"Ich werde den Branch auschecken."

I am a german native speaker, but I can't really decide on this.
The literal translation of "branch" is "Ast", which would use the male "der".
My intuition on the other hand seems to point towards the female "die".

Any sources would be appreciated.

Comment: Wenn du Muttersprachler bist, solltest du deine Frage auch auf Deutsch stellen.

Comment: @Annatar: nein, man kann es aber man muss es nicht, vor allem dann nicht, wenn sich die Frage nicht nur an deutsche Muttersprachler richten soll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei Eindeutschungen werden die Artikel der deutschen Übersetzung übernommen. Deswegen: Der Branch. (dt.: der Ast)<sup>[(1)](https://www.pcs-campus.de/kommunikation/texten/anglizismen/)</sup>

EDIT: Manchmal gibt es Ausnahmen, wenn die zugrunde liegende Übersetzung etwas unklar ist, wie z.B. - wenn wir in der Computerbranche bleiben - bei (oft so betitelt) "die Semaphore", welche genaugenommen "der Semaphor" heißen müsste, aber es wurde wohl nach dem Lautbild abgeleitet.

Comment: Die Branch klingt übrigens furchtbar. "Die Branch" habe ich aber auch noch keinen Programmierer sagen gehört...

Comment: Ich habe heute zum ersten mal bewusst "der branch" gehört.

Comment: Die Artikel werden **normalerweise** übernommen... aber nicht immer (bzw. ist oft unklar, was genau die Primärübersetzung ist). In diesem Fall allerdings schon, da deckt sich meine Erfahrung mit deiner (arbeite in der *Branche*).

Comment: Ich habe schon erlebt, dass sich in manchen Firmen falsche Artikel bzw. auch Begriffe oder Aussprache durchsetzen durch Herdentrieb, wenn es einflussreiche Kollegen so benutzen. Inselkultur sozusagen...

Comment: Es gibt natürlich auch das alte Lehnwort “die Branche” (aus dem Französischen).

Comment: @fdb: Nein, der Fall ist ganz klar. Das Versionsverwaltungssystem (SVN, git, ...) VERZWEIGT vom Trunk (der Stamm) auf den Branch (der Ast). Die Computerfachsprache ist Englisch. Französisch spielt da keine Rolle.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass engl. „branch“ auch dem frz. „branche“ entlehnt ist.

Comment: Die Informatik entlehnt aber aus dem Englischen und nicht aus dessen Vorgängerentlehnungen... ;)